# Error while deploying permission set using migration tool

Tags: permission-sets

I was trying to deploy a new Permission Set using the ANT migration tool (Custom java classes wrapping the ANT migration tool). I encountered the following error during deployment:

```
permissionsets/MyPermSet.permissionset(null, null:Permission ManageTwoFactor depends on permission(s): DelegatedTwoFactor
```

. My current permission set looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<description>Permission Included = System Permissions: Managing Users (Various)</description>
<label>MyPermSet</label>
<userLicense>Salesforce</userLicense>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>AssignPermissionSets</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageInternalUsers</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageIpAddresses</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageLoginAccessPolicies</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManagePasswordPolicies</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageProfilesPermissionsets</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageRoles</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageSharing</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageUsers</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageTwoFactor</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ForceTwoFactor</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>TwoFactorApi</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ResetPasswords</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ViewAllUsers</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ViewSetup</name>
</userPermissions>
</PermissionSet>
```

After searching on Google for a while and trying a couple of things, I took a punt and added the permission:

```
<userPermissions>
   <enabled>true</enabled>
   <name>DelegatedTwoFactor</name>
</userPermissions>
```

This fixed my problem, but I am uncomfortable with doing this because I don't fully understand what exactly this permission will allow or enforce. I wasn't able to find a suitable match for **DelegatedTwoFactor** in the Salesforce User Interface under System Permissions either (but I did not spend too much time on it, I confess!)

My question is, does anyone know what this allow and how it gets mapped in the Salesforce UI?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you deploying from sandbox to sandbox?

Answer (score 2):

I think your source (that allowed you to create PermissionSet) is on Spring 16 and destination is on Summer 16.

DelegatedTwoFactor is new Summer16 permission, you can read more here:

[release notes summer 16](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_security_auth_new_ui_2fa_mgmt_perm.htm)

overall it is inbound into “Manage Users” and can not be removed from it.

Answer (score 0):

The Manage Two Factor authentication provides your admins to enable or disable Two Factor Authentication and control various settings related to two factor authentication .

To learn more about two factor authentication ,please follow [this](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_require_two_factor_authentication.htm)

With Delegated Two factor enabled for a permission set ,you

> Let users who aren’t Salesforce admins provide support for two-factor authentication in your org. For example, suppose you want your company’s Help Desk staff to generate temporary verification codes for users who lost or forgot the device they usually use for two-factor authentication. Assign Help Desk staff members the “Manage Two-Factor Authentication in User Interface” permission so that they can generate codes and support end users with other two-factor authentication tasks.

Check [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_delegate_2fa_mgt_ui.htm&language=en_US) for more info  .